# Websocket with flutter_web

Tags: flutter, websocket

I have a flutter X application that opens a websocket to communicate with other flutter applications. The following code works in the case where the X application is in desktop or mobile (there is a mobile overlay with deeplink).
I would like to know if it is possible to adapt my following code to allow communication between client applications and my application X in the case of the web with flutter_web?

In short: a web application creates a websocket with my X application. Is it possible ?

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:developer';
import 'dart:io';

class WebsocketRPCServer {
  WebsocketRPCServer({
    required this.commandDispatcher,
  });

  static const logName = 'RPC Server';
  static const host = '127.0.0.1';
  static const port = 12345;

  final CommandDispatcher commandDispatcher;

  static bool get isPlatformCompatible {
    return !kIsWeb &&
        (Platform.isLinux || Platform.isMacOS || Platform.isWindows);
  }

  Future<void> run() async {
    runZonedGuarded(
      () async {
        log('Starting at ws://$host:$port', name: logName);
        final server = await HttpServer.bind(
          host,
          port,
          shared: true,
        );

        server.listen((HttpRequest request) async {
          log('Received request', name: logName);

          final socket = await WebSocketTransformer.upgrade(request);
          final channel = IOWebSocketChannel(socket);

          final server = _SubscribablePeer(Peer(channel.cast<String>()))
            ..registerMethod(
              'sendTransaction',
              (params) => _handle(RPCSendTransactionCommandHandler(), params),
            )
            ..registerMethod(
              'getEndpoint',
              (params) => _handle(RPCGetEndpointCommandHandler(), params),
            );
            

          await server.listen();
        });
      },
      (error, stack) {
        log(
          'WebSocket server failed',
          error: error,
          stackTrace: stack,
          name: logName,
        );
      },
    );
  }
```